# how to set spring active profile environment variable in IntelliJ

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot

I am using spring boot application (maven project) in eclipse. When I run test clean target of maven project, I want to load the active profiles

I have added the property spring.profiles.active=test,aop in application.properties and also in application-test.properties, this does not have any affect.

or setting this property in command line option of IntelliJ IDE  as -Dspring.profiles.active=test,aop does not have an effect when the command is test clean. I have also tried setting the JVM argument of the Runner in Intelligent

however @ActiveProfiles("test") works when the test case class is executed from IntelliJ IDE( right click -> run TestCaseClass).

Any clues ?

Comment: Setting the VM Option `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`, for example, works for me just fine.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Setting the VM Options with `-Dspring.profiles.active=test`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this still accurate in the newest Spring Boot? I heard that they changed the property name that's used to set the active profile.

Comment: yes, `spring.profiles.active` is still the correct property name, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.profiles

Answer (score 0):

My Project is using MAVEN. 
the easy was is 
Right hand side click on MAVEN -> Expand the Profiles -> Click on desired profile.
Build and run
Please check the attached screenshot for more clarity

[image]